# User Defined Value Types

Tags: solidity

In documentation :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

// Represent a 18 decimal, 256 bit wide fixed point type
// using a user defined value type.
type UFixed is uint256;

/// A minimal library to do fixed point operations on UFixed.
library FixedMath {
    uint constant multiplier = 10**18;

    /// Adds two UFixed numbers. Reverts on overflow, 
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function add(UFixed a, UFixed b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) + UFixed.unwrap(b));
    }
    /// Multiplies UFixed and uint256. Reverts on overflow,
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function mul(UFixed a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) * b);
    }
    /// Take the floor of a UFixed number.
    /// @return the largest integer that does not exceed `a`.
    function floor(UFixed a) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return UFixed.unwrap(a) / multiplier;
    }
    /// Turns a uint256 into a UFixed of the same value.
    /// Reverts if the integer is too large.
    function toUFixed(uint256 a) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(a * multiplier);
    }
}
```

Notice how UFixed.wrap and FixedMath.toUFixed have the same signature but perform two very different operations: The UFixed.wrap function returns a UFixed that has the same data representation as the input, whereas toUFixed returns a UFixed that has the same numerical value. One can allow some form of type-encapsulation by only using the wrap and unwrap functions in the file that defines the type.

I did not understand what documentation wants to say, could you clarify this ?

Comment: You might find it helpful to take a look at [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math), the first fixed-point math library to make use of user-defined value types.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the line:

```js
uint constant multiplier = 10**18;
```

The library `FixedMath` is creating an abstraction for a `uin256` type, using the last 18 digits of the `uint256` as the decimals of this fixed-point number. This library will allow treating a `uint256` integer as if it was a floating point number, where the last 18 digits of the `uint256` will be the decimal.

***Notice how UFixed.wrap and FixedMath.toUFixed have the same signature***, just means that both `UFixed.wrap` and `FixedMath.toUFixed` functions receive a `uint256` integer, but both functions treat it differently.

Using `UFixed.wrap` directly just wraps whatever you pass to it as it. For example `UFixed uf = UFixed.wrap(5)`, when you do `UFixed.unwrap(uf)` it will return a `5`.
But, if you call `FixedMath.toUFixed(5)` and let's assume that it allows get the underlying `uint256` value as is, it would be `5000000000000000000`, because it is multiplying 5 by `multiplier` which is `10 ** 18` so it can use the last 18 digits as the decimal. So, this library would treat `5000000000000000000` as if it was `5.000000000000000000`.

As you know, Solidity does not support floating/fixed point numbers. So, libraries like this are common, that use `uint256` and dedicate certain digits to act as the decimal value.

So, what the documentation is trying to tell you is that you can use an abstraction like this for `uint256` or other types, and only use it through the `.wrap`/`.unwrap`, or directly in all the references, and only use the underlying value when needed.

For example, check the following simply contract where I created a custom type `UserId`, and notice how I never had to use the `.wrap` or `.unwrap` functions because I used the `UserId` reference everywhere instead of receiving a `uint256` and then having to `wrap` it to a `UserId` type:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

type UserId is uint256;

contract Contract {

    mapping(UserId => User) public users;

    struct User {
        UserId id;
        string name;
    }

    function getUser(UserId userId) public view returns(User memory) {
        return users[userId];
    }

}
```

Only if we need to do a calculation with the `userId` is when we would need to use the `unwrap` function. But, if we create a library that can handle all the details of those calculations and it would receive a `UserId` (or whatever custom type`, do the calculation internally and then return us the result as the custom type, we would never need to see the details of it (we would not need to see the` uint256`ourselves using`unwrap`). Hence, it would be abstracted and would be easier to use.

For example, check the following contract that now is using the `FixedMath` library:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

type UserId is uint256;
type UFixed is uint256;

/// A minimal library to do fixed point operations on UFixed.
library FixedMath {
    uint constant multiplier = 10**18;

    /// Adds two UFixed numbers. Reverts on overflow, 
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function add(UFixed a, UFixed b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) + UFixed.unwrap(b));
    }
    /// Multiplies UFixed and uint256. Reverts on overflow,
    /// relying on checked arithmetic on uint256.
    function mul(UFixed a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(UFixed.unwrap(a) * b);
    }
    /// Take the floor of a UFixed number.
    /// @return the largest integer that does not exceed `a`.
    function floor(UFixed a) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return UFixed.unwrap(a) / multiplier;
    }
    /// Turns a uint256 into a UFixed of the same value.
    /// Reverts if the integer is too large.
    function toUFixed(uint256 a) internal pure returns (UFixed) {
        return UFixed.wrap(a * multiplier);
    }
}

contract Contract {
    using FixedMath for UFixed;

    mapping(UserId => User) public users;

    struct User {
        UserId id;
        string name;
    }

    function getUser(UserId userId) public view returns(User memory) {
        return users[userId];
    }

    function add(UFixed a, UFixed b) public pure returns(UFixed) {
        return a.add(b);
    }

}
```

Notice the line `using FixedMath for UFixed;`, to use the functions in the `FixedMath` library as it they were members of the `UFixed` type to use them directly like `uf1.add(uf2)` instead of `FixedMath.add(uf1, uf2)`.

Check the `add` function in the `Contract` contract. It receives 2 `UFixed`, make add them and returns a `UFixed`. I never had to `wrap` or `unwrap` anything or do the calculation myself. All that is abstracted in the `FixedMath` library.